# comment is added to the wrong answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

- start writing a comment
- new answer is submitted
- update view to see the new answer
- end writing the comment

What I expect: the comment is added to the first answer.

What happens instead: the comment is added to the new answer.

It has happened once. I haven't tried to repeat it.

app version: 1.0.1 05/13/20141.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug here occurred because commenting was **indexed-based, instead of answer-based**. When a new answer was loaded, if it happened to have a better score than the answer we're commenting on, it would replace it. However, the comment would get added to the new answer, which had the same index.

This issue has been fixed in the latest codebase; it should be reflected in the Appstore on the next release.